# Quelle est la structure grammaticale de "Je suis un peu fatigué" ?

Tags: grammaire

Dans "Je suis un peu fatigué", "peu" est un nom, l'objet du verbe être, et fatigué est un adjectif qui a l'air de s'appliquer au nom "peu". Interprétée littéralement, cette phrase semble donc dire:

> Je suis une sorte de chose appelé un "Peu", et en particulier la sorte de Peu que je suis est un Peu qui est fatigué.

Après tout, si on remplace "peu" par "homme", la phrase a exactement ce sens là. Comment expliquer la grammaire de cette phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pour faire très simple, "[un peu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un_peu)" est une [locution adverbiale](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/locution_adverbiale), c'est-à-dire un groupe de mots se comportant comme un adverbe.

Il faut donc le considérer comme un adverbe.

> Je suis *un peu* fatigué

a donc la même structure que :

> Je suis *très* fatigué

C'est aussi simple que ça :)

Comment: Ha, c'est vrai. Tout dépend du niveau de précision souhaité.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, c'est sûr ^^

Answer (score 7):

Oui, il est difficile d'éviter cette lecture. Néanmoins, le comportement des éléments nous montrera que cette phrase ne partage pas la structure de « Je suis un homme fatigué ».

---

Voici une analyse de cette dernière.<sup>1</sup>

> (1a) Je<sub>n<sup>(1)</sup></sub> suis<sub>v</sub> [un<sub>det<sup>(gouv. n2)</sup></sub> ( homme<sub>n<sup>(2)</sup></sub> fatigué<sub>adj<sup>(gouv. n2)</sup></sub>) ]<sub>GN</sub>

Ici on a un groupe nominal « un homme fatigué » dont la tête est « homme », qui gouverne (pour l'objet de l'accord) l'adjectif « fatigué » et le déterminant « un ». Le tout est le complément du verbe « suis ».

Donc ce que tu proposes pourrait être :

> (1b) Je<sub>n<sup>(1)</sup></sub> suis<sub>v</sub> [un<sub>det<sup>(gouv. n2)</sup></sub> ( peu<sub>n<sup>(2)</sup></sub> fatigué<sub>adj<sup>(gouv. n2)</sup></sub>) ]<sub>GN</sub>

Là, comme tu le dis, je pourrais être cette chose qui s'appelle un « peu », ce qui serait étrange.

L'alternatif est le suivant :

> (2) Je<sub>n<sup>(1)</sup></sub> suis<sub>v</sub> [ [ un<sub>det<sup>(gouv. n2)</sup></sub> peu<sub>n<sup>(2)</sup></sub> ]<sub>GN</sub> fatigué <sub>adj<sup>(gouv. n1)</sup></sub> ]<sub>GAdj</sub>

Ici, « un peu » est un groupe nominal, mais ce groupe fonctionne en tant qu'adverbe. Cet « adverbe » modifie « fatigué », adjectif qui est la tête du groupe adjectival. Comme avant, « peu » gouverne « un », mais cette fois « fatigué » est gouverné par « je ». (Comment ça marche avec les verbes couples est une autre histoire.)

Sachant cela, on découvrira la vraie syntaxe en changeant les deux noms en noms féminins (ou pluriels, bien sûr). Comme « fatigué » s'accord avec le deuxième nom dans les structures (1a, b) mais avec le premier nom (le pronom sujet) dans la structure (2), le comportement de ce mot nous permettra de décider quelle est la structure adéquate pour « un peu ».

Voici ce qu'on trouvera<sup>2</sup> :

- Quant à la phrase « Je suis un homme fatigué », si on change « un homme » à « une personne », il faudra mettre un autre « e » à la fin de « fatigué » pour faire l'accord. Mais si on change le sujet « je » en « tu, il, elle, ce » etc. tout en laissant « un homme », « fatigué » ne doit pas changer.

> Cet homme est une personne fatiguée.
>   
> Cette personne est un homme fatigué.

- Quant à la phrase « Je suis un peu fatigué », par contre, le changement du sujet pronominal provoquera un changement pareil chez « fatigué ».

> Il est un peu fatigué.
>   
> Elle est un peu fatiguée.

Dès lors, on peut voir que la syntaxe de « un peu » doit être la structure de (2) et non celle de (1a, b).

---

<sup>1 La syntaxe dans cette réponse n'est analysée qu'au niveau exigé pour marquer le point.</sup>

<sup>2 Si nous trouvons ces définitions théoriques, il ne faut que changer l'adjectif en un autre dont l'accord soit audible, comme « sportif / ive », pour baser notre opinion sur l'usage intuitif.</sup>